# how to get error response in angular while calling an api?

Tags: angular, web-services

when i m calling an api by providing wrong credential i m getting an error response in postman.
but when the same is called by angular i m getting different error status.

```
 login(loginFormData){
    this.service.login(loginFormData.value.username,loginFormData.value.password).subscribe((res:any)=>{      
      if(res.status.code == 1){
        this.route.navigate(['/dashboard'], { replaceUrl: true });
      }
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      this.errorMsg = "Oops!!Something went wrong.";
    });
  }
}
```

[image: this is the response which i m getting through postman]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is expected and  working via postman is postman doesn't send preflight requests while your browser does.You can fix it in two ways,

Solution 1 - you need to change your backend to accept your incoming requests

Solution 2 - using Angular proxy [see here](https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d)

Comment: I m getting the expected output in postman.But my query is why i m not gettting the same error response in log?

Comment: cant you see it in the answer why its working in postman? do you know about CORS?

Comment: Its hitting my webServices also , there is no need to set proxy

Comment: Yes bro, through ui its hitting the same webService

Comment: I am repeating the same again. Read about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS here, thats your issue